# Security Vulnerability to open IOT devices to the internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security, iot, microcontroller

I am currently learning how to use the Raspberry Pi Pico W, a relatively new IOT Microcontroller device using the RP2040. It's possible to open a small web server with it so I really would like to interact with it over the internet. How big of a security vulnerabilty would it be to forward a port to that device?

I have a Samba NAS-Server (secured with a username/password) on my network and would hate to have some stranger access or modify my files.

P.S. Is superuser an ok forum to ask security-related questions? Didn't know anything better :/

Comment: If you're just going to use in on your LAN, give it a private IP address on the inside and hit it directly. Why do you feel that you need NAT loopback?

Comment: I'm sorry, just realized I'm a bit dumb. Still, would it be a security risk?

Comment: What web server are you going to use? What applications are you running? That will matter more than the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device isn't inherently vulnerable or secure. You'll need to treat it like any server and keep it updated and secured as much as possible. If your router allows you to create multiple internal networks or a DMZ or secure server area, also consider doing that to protect your internal network. Only expose your web ports (usually TCP 80 and 443), disable unneeded modules, and check your code and configuration.